# How to Mimic n-gram model using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, n-gram

How to create an N-gram model using tensorflow that predicts/compute the frequency of a word?

let say the model will return a value that corresponds to the frequency of a word.

```
frequency = model("word")

print("Frequency of a word: ",frequency)

>>> Frequency of a word: 0.567
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Tensorflow Transofrm`](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform). `tf.Transform` is an official library for preprocessing data with TensorFlow. For example, with [`tf.Transform.ngrams`](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/docs/api_docs/python/tft/ngrams.md), you can create a `SparseTensor` of n-grams.

**Pay attention** that the library only generates ngrams but not frequency.

Be sure to install tensorflow transform:

```
pip install tensorflow-transform
```